# How to get the exact mouse down coordinate? Why my code does not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, dom-events

I would like to show something at the mouse down place, I tried to use :

```
$('#my-graph').mousedown(function(evt){

      // show object at:
      var x= evt.screenX, y=evt.screenY;

      //or show object at:
     var x2=evt.pageX, y2=evt.pageY;

     //code to render object at (x,y) and (x2,y2)
     ......  
});
```

But neither of the above (x, y) and (x2,y2) place the rendered object at the mouse clicked place, and show the object some distance away from mouse down place, why?

I render the object with a position attributes, the position is relative to the **#my-graph** div, left up most corner of the div is supposed to be the origin point(0,0)

Comment: What do you expect the coordinates to mean? I mean, relative to what? The page, the screen or an element?

Comment: Do you render the object using proper position attributes? E.g. position: absolute in relevance to screen?

Comment: Yes, I render the position with a position attributes, in relavant with the #my-graph div, left up most corner of the div is supposed to be the origin point

Answer (score 5):

You seem to want `offsetX` and `offsetY`: http://jsfiddle.net/f52Gg/.

```
$("div").mousedown(function(e){
    alert(e.offsetX + " " + e.offsetY);
});
```

Comment: I don't think this is supported in Firefox, use `e.layerX` and `e.layerY` instead

Comment: @Bugster: Firefox doesn't seem to support `offsetX`, but WebKit doesn't support `layerX`. What is also possible is subtracting the offset of the element from `pageX`.